# Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::setContainer does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Seeders:

```
class CouponTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $coupons = (array)factory(\App\Coupon::class,10)->make();
    Log::info('Created coupons.. ', $coupons);
}
}


class CompanyTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $companies = (array)factory(\App\Company::class,10)->make();
    Log::info('Company users.. ', $companies);
}
}


class CustomerTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $customers = (array)factory(\App\Customer::class,10)->make();
    Log::info('Created customers.. ', $customers);
}
}


class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $users = (array)factory(User::class,10)->make();
    Log::info('Created users.. ', $users);

}
}

class DBSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $classes = [\App\Company::class,\App\Customer::class,\App\Coupon::class,\App\Employee::class,\App\User::class];
    $this->call($classes);
}
}
```

After i run  `php artisan db:seed --class=DBSeeder`
I got the error after Seeding: App\Company:

> > BadMethodCallException  : Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::setContainer does not exist.

Whole trace :

Exception trace:

> > > 1   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::__call("setContainer")
> > >             /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sites/FakeProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:1288
> > >
> > > 2   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::__call("setContainer")
> > >             /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sites/FakeProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1511

Factories:

```
$factory->define(Company::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    "company_id"=>$faker->randomNumber(3000),
    "logo"=>$faker->unique()->company
];
});

$factory->define(Coupon::class, function (Faker $faker) {
$types = ['Food','Travelling','Camping','Sport','Restaurants','Health'];
return [
    "coupon_id"=>$faker->unique()->randomNumber(2000),
    "title"=>$faker->unique()->randomLetter,
    'amount'=>rand(1,50),
    'price'=>(double)rand(1,100),
    'type'=>array_rand($types),
    'created_at'=>\Carbon\Carbon::now(),
    'expired_at'=>\Carbon\Carbon::create(rand(2018,2020),rand(1,12),rand(1,31))
];
});

$factory->define(Customer::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'customer_id'=>$faker->unique()->randomNumber(1000),
        'first_name'=>$faker->name,
        'last_name'=>$faker->name,
        'nickname'=>$faker->unique()->userName,
        'email'=>$faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password'=>$faker->unique()->password
    ];
});

$factory->define(Employee::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'employee_id'=>$faker->unique()->randomNumber(1000),
        'first_name'=>$faker->name,
        'last_name'=>$faker->name,
        'nickname'=>$faker->unique()->userName,
        'email'=>$faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password'=>$faker->unique()->password
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_nickname' => $faker->unique()->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => crypt(rand(1,1000),'plmaks'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
        'id'=>$faker->unique()->randomNumber(3000),
        'created_at'=>Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at'=>Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not calling Models in `DBSeeder` , call your Seeder classes :

```
class DBSeeder extends Seeder
{
 /**
  * Run the database seeds.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function run()
  {

    $classes =[UserTableSeeder::class,
               CompanyTableSeeder::class,
               CustomerTableSeeder::class,
               CouponTableSeeder::class,
               ];

   $this->call($classes);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The error itself is not self explanatory . Problem solved!

Comment: you're welcome ;) , yeah itself is  not self explanatory .